# Does a hyperelliptic Riemann surface $S$ with $\# Aut(S)=2$ exist?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

If a Riemann surface $S$ has genus $g\geq 2$, its automotphisms group is finite. I was wondering if there exists a hyperelliptic Riemann surface $S$ with $\# Aut(S)=2$. In other words, I was wondering if the hyperelliptic involution $J:S\rightarrow S$ is the generator of the automorphisms group of any hyperelliptic Riemann surface $S$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the results contained in

Poonen, Varieties without extra automorphisms II: hyperelliptic curves

for any genus $g\geq 2$ there exists a hyperelliptic Riemann surface with just two automorphisms: the identity and the hyperelliptic involution. On the other hand it is proved in

Gutierrez, Shaska, Hyperelliptic Curves with Extra Involutions

that the locus of genus $g$ hyperelliptic curves which admit extra involutions (besides the hyperelliptic one) is a  $g$-dimensional subvariety of the moduli space of hyperelliptic curves.